# How to define a set of interfaces to combine reading/modifying operations in one list but handle them differently upon execution

Tags: c#, interface

I have a text that shall be processed/used by a couple of functions which the user has to enter in a sequence, e.g. an array.

Some pseudo code:

```
var text = "the text that shall be extracted\n"
          + "by some and only read by others\n";

var functions = new ThisInterfaceImInterestedIn[]
                    { 
                        aFunctionThatModifiesText,
                        aFunctionThatOnlyReadsTheText,     // these two shall be processed in parallel!
                        anotherFunctionThatOnlyReadsText,  // these two shall be processed in parallel!
                        anotherFunctionThatModifiesText,   // even this could be processed in parallel
                                                           // since it uses the same input as the two above
                        modifyingFunction3, // but not this
                        //...
                    };        

var newText = process(text, functions);
```

I'm looking for a good interface/ set of interfaces that allows these optimizations through parallel execution that does **not** rely on casting/type checks.
I *could* form a set of interfaces like these:

```
interface ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  // only a marker
}

interface ITextReader : ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  void useText(string text);
}

interface ITextModifier : ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  string modifyText(string text);
}
```

and do a type-check in the processor to determine if the function modifies/uses the text.

But this doesn't feel like "the right way to do it" for me.

---

An example:

The processing of the functions mentioned above should be in this way:

```
string theOriginalText = ...;

string textV1 = aFunctionThatModifiesText.modifyText(theOriginalText);
// this blocks execution until the modification is finished

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  aFunctionThatOnlyReadsTheText.useText(textV1));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  anotherFunctionThatOnlyReadsText.useText(textV1));
// don't wait for them to finish

string textV2 = anotherFunctionThatModifiesText.modifyText(textV1);
// this blocks execution until the modification is finished

string textV4 = modifyingFunction3(textV4);
// this blocks execution until the modification is finished

//...
```

This forces the execution to wait for modification to be finished but don't wait for readers to finish to continue processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put a flag in your interface indicating that it modifies or reads text ? Something like this:

```
interface ITextProcessor
{
    string ProcessText(string text);
    bool IModifyText;
}
```

This way you can do what you want without casting.

Edit: if this model is confusing for users of the class you can add a layer of abstraction and hide ITextProcessor members using explicit imlementation of ITextProcessor interface. This way users of concrete classes won't see ITextProcessors members.

```
public abstract class TextReader : ITextProcessor
{
    string ITextProcessor.ProcessText(string input)
    {
        Read(input);
        return input;
    }

    bool ITextProcessor.IModifyText
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public abstract void Read(string input);
}

public abstract class TextModifier : ITextProcessor
{
    string ITextProcessor.ProcessText(string input)
    {
        return Modify(input);
    }

    bool ITextProcessor.IModifyText
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public abstract string Modify(string input);
}

public class SampleModifier : TextModifier
{
    public override string Modify(string input)
    {
        return input + " !MODIFIED!";
    }
}

public class SampleReader : TextReader
{
    public override void Read(string input)
    {
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lst = new List<ITextProcessor> { new SampleModifier(), new SampleReader() };


    Console.WriteLine("USING MODIFIERS");
    foreach (var a in lst.Where(x => x.IModifyText))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.ProcessText("Hi modifier"));
    }


    Console.WriteLine("USING READERS");
    foreach (var a in lst.Where(x => !x.IModifyText))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.ProcessText("Hi reader"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So a "reader" would have to return the input `text`? Or `null`? Or whatever it likes since the surrounding logic will discard it anyway?

Comment: You can do it both ways, I would return the input text.

Comment: It's a really simple interface - that's good. But it would force a `reader` to implement `ProcessText` and this method might be confusing users that use the class standalone - that's drawback.

Comment: To be honest it's not that confusing, but if you think it is you can add two abstract classes that implement this interface **explicitly** and each expose a Write or Read method.

Comment: The new version is much better and the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would just mark all parallel modifiers/readers with one more marker interface (e.g. IParallelTextReaderOrModifier). This way you do not need to check concrete types (just the marker interface). And also this has an advantage that you do not need to implement any extra logic in the concrete Reader/Modifier classes themselves.

```
interface ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  // only a marker
}

interface IParallelTextReaderOrModifier
{
  // only a marker
}

interface ITextReader : ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  void useText(string text);
}

interface ITextModifier : ITextReaderOrModifier
{
  string modifyText(string text);
}

public class ConcreteImplementationOfTextModifier : ITextModifier
{
  ...
}

public class ConcreteImplementationOfParallelTextModifier : ITextModifier, IParallelTextReaderOrModifier
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Modifiers can by their nature never be executed in parallel, can they? So of what use would be a `ConcreteImplementationOfParallelTextModifier`? Readers are always parallel, so I can merge the interfaces`IParallelTextReaderOrModifier` and `ITextReader`.

Comment: Why then you have a comment "even this could be processed in parallel" for a modifier? It actually depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to have some modifiers that allow readers to access values during the process of a non-atomic update, IParallelTextReaderOrModifier might make sense.

Comment: The last modifier can be processed in parallel but only since the readers before don't change the text and so don't influence the final text of the function executed in parallel. After the reader is finished, it's result is passed on down the processing line. But a reader can only be processed in parallel due to it's position (i.e. after some readers).

Comment: Not sure I understand the idea. How will you make sure that anotherFunctionThatModifiesText is not executed before the 2 readers? In this case there will be a race condition - result obtained by readers might vary.

Comment: I'll add an example to the question, that will hopefully clarify this point.

Comment: What stops anotherFunctionThatModifiesText.modifyText() from finishing its work before the read functions? (e.g. if execution of read functions takes longer than the write operation for some reason). From what I see in your code, the call to anotherFunctionThatModifiesText.modifyText() only blocks execution of modifyingFunction3(), not of itself or any of the read functions.

Comment: That's right. But it doesn't matter if the readers finish before/after anotherFunctionThatModifiesText, since they don't influence subsequent readers/modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is good enough :) if you object to marker interface, I would change the logic to:

```
public interface ITextOperator {
  void Execute(string text);
}

public interface ITextWriter : ITextOperator {
  string Result { get; }
}

public class TextReader : ITextOperator {
  public void Execute(string text) {
    // do something with text
  }
}

public class TextWriter : ITextWriter {
  public void Execute(string text) {
    // do something with text
    // store result in Result property
  }

  public string Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I dislike the fact that I could access the `Result` before the execution. Also the class by itself would be harder to use if used in a standalone fashion.